# ruby: Give out a shell script with variables

Tags: ruby, shell

Actually i have a Shellscript which gives out a second modified script like so:

```
cat <<EOF > $TITEL/de-DE/build.sh
#!/bin/bash
[My Stuff]
EOF
```

The second shellscript has variables in it. So the variables are going to resolved and puts out a Shellscript.

Is it possible to do such thing in ruby? So that ruby resolves the variables and produces a shell script?

Or is it a better solution to place the script in my Gemdirectory and copy it on the wished place. So a gsub replace can resolve the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby has heredoc strings too. "#{}" in heredoc strings gets interpolated as usual.

```
string = <<EOF
puts '#{__FILE__}' #__FILE__ gets interpolated
#the comments are part of the string
EOF
```

You can write a string into a file with `File.write(file_name, string)`.

```
#Combined
File.write file_name, <<EOF
#...
EOF
```